# Group sequence value in column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, gaps-and-islands

Table **mytbl** have two columns: *col_1* & *col_2*. I wanted to group range of values in *col_1* for single *col_2* value.

Example:

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 10 | 1 |

I wanted to filter out the a range for *col_2* = 3.

it shows hiphen(-) for the ***end*** value when there is no range.

Result:

| start | end | col_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | - | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 7 | 9 | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps and island problem. Here is an approach using the difference between row numbers to identify the groups:

```
select 
    min(col_1) as start_col_1, 
    case when max(col_1) <> min(col_1) then max(col_1) end as end_col_1, 
    col2
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by col2 order by col_1) as rn
    from mytable t
) t
where col_2 = 3
group by col2, col_1 - rn
order by start_col1
```

This returns `null` rather than `'-'` when the islands is made of just one record (that is because the latter is not a valid number).

This works as long as `col_1` increments without gaps. Else, we can generate our own sequence with another `row_number()`:

```
select 
    min(col_1) as start_col_1, 
    case when max(col_1) <> min(col_1) then max(col_1) end as end_col_1, 
    col2
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(order by col_1) as rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by col2 order by col_1) as rn2
    from mytable t
) t
where col_2 = 3
group by col2, rn1 - rn2
order by start_col1
```

Comment: I'm testing it with a huge data. The second one works fine but I wanted to add another condition to my where clause (actually filter by date if it may help)